# Shared Static Assets for Multilingual

Tags: localization, craft4

I'm trying to do a multilingual site e.g. `/nl` `/de` though when browsing to these URL's all is working apart from the static images hosted in `.../nl/web/img` it seems to be looking for URL's still within the base URL.

Is there a way to setup the site so that it properly fetches shared static assets for multilingual sites? Or what is the best way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Please include screenshots of your file system and asset volume configuration, as well as the Settings -> Websites settings and any relevant `.env` variables and the physical directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

At my site I use the same top level domain name. So it's always `/assets/img` based on the root. So `domainname.tld/assets/img`and not `domainname.tld/de/assets/img`

Or go away from hosting your assets locally on your server. I use Amazon S3 for most of my side projects for hosting images. And then I don't care what my domain structure is for assets.

Comment: And how does your templating look to get an image at that root domain?

Comment: Ok, in my current setup it's not always the root. Sorry for that.

First I had the problem with the CSS, because I loaded the CSS with just something like `../assets/css/main.css`

I changed this to `{% css "/assets/css/main.css" %}`. I load my favicons in my `<head>`with something like `{{ url('assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png') }}`

This way, my Twig will output: `https://domainname.io/de/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png` at my german site and `https://domainname.io/assets/images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png`at the english site.

Answer (score 0):

If the sites all share the same top level domain name, I would use site-root relative paths for your asset base URLs (i.e., ones that start with a forward slash: `/img`), and similar for your asset base path: `/server/path/to/img`, so that they all point to the same directory. If the sites use separate top level domain names, I would create symlinks on the server to achieve the same thing (pointing them all to a canonical directory on the primary site so that I can still use root-relative paths).